# C# Reflection Invoke - Object of Type 'XXX' Cannot Be Converted to type 'System.Object[]'

Tags: c#, reflection

I have created an instance called `input` that is of type:

```
public class TestInput
{
    public int TesTInt { get; set; }
}
```

I use this in this function:

```
public static class TestClass
{
    public static string TestFunction()
    {
        var testInput = new TestInput();
        string res = ServicesManager.Execute<string>((object) testInput);

        return res;
    }
}
```

The `Execute` function is here:

```
public static OUT Execute<OUT>(object input) 
            where OUT : class
{
       var method = //getting method by reflection
       object[] arr = new object[] { input };
       return method.Invoke(null, arr) as OUT; //Error is triggered here
}
```

The method that I invoke is this one:

```
public static string TestFunctionProxy(object[] input)
{
       var serviceInput = input[0] as TestInput;
       //rest of code
}
```

I received the error in the title. (XXX - "TestInput" type)

What's happening and what is causing this error?

Note: `method` is static so no instance is required for the first parameter. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** Updated the question with some more code for a complete example.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided a short but *complete* example. I also suspect that the error message didn't include "XXX". And we don't know where you're getting the error...

Comment: @JonSkeet Fair enough, will update the question.

Comment: Casting as object and casting as ARRAY of objects is two different things. What *exact* parameters types is your method expecting to receive?

Comment: What method are you trying to invoke exactly? What are it's parameters? There's not enough information here. Remember reflection isn't magic - make sure your parameters all match the compile time parameter lists.

Comment: @JonSkeet Updated my question with some more information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are passing the wrong arguments to the method. It wants an object[] and you are giving a simpe object. This is how to fix it:

```
object[] arr = new object[] { new object[] { input } };
```

The 'outer' object[] is the parameter for Invoke, the 'inner' array is the parameter for your method.